# Logging out a user when it has been deleted by admin user

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, spring-security

At the moment I am trying to delete a user which is logged in say at other system or on a different browser using an admin user.

Now when a user has been deleted it should get logged out from wherever it is logged in .

I have stopped user from log into an application twice at  a particular moment using spring security session management (concurrency control)http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/ServerDoc2x/Concurrent+Sessions+(Preventing+Users+from+Logging+in+More+Than+Once)

But the point is when it has been deleted the session should get invalidated for that user and it should log out and should not  able to login back as it has been deleted.

The underlying database is marklogic ,I can get active sessionId for that user but I should be able to invalidate that session as well.

Please let me know what are the available options?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Spring security's `SessionRegistry`.

A code snippet along the lines of this one below should do it:

```
    List<SessionInformation> userSessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(user, false);
    for (SessionInformation sessionInfo : userSessions) {
        sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(sessionInfo.getSessionId());
    }
```

You should be able to autowire SessionRegistry and then use it as described above.

If you already know user's sessionId then the following code should work as well:

```
sessionRegistry.removeSessionInformation(sessiondId);
```